# Am I reinventing the (squared) wheel?

Tags: macros, dictionary, clojure

As we should know, Clojure's `map` can be applied to a sequence:

```
(map #(* %1 %1) [1 2 3])           ; (1)
```

..or to more than one, in this way:

```
(map vector [0 1] [2 1])           ; (2)
;=> ([0 2] [1 1])
```

Now I want to obtain the same result as (2), but I have the arguments stored inside a sequence. In other words, the following does not give the desired result:

```
(map vector [[0 1] [2 1]])         ; (3)
;=> ([[0 1]] [[2 1]])
```

So I've written this simple macro, where umap stands for "unsplice map":

```
(defmacro umap [fun args-list]
  "umap stands for unspliced map.
  Let args-list be a list of args [a1 a2 ... an].
  umap is the same of (map fun a1 a2 .. an)"
  `(map ~fun ~@args-list))
```

Obviously it works like a charm:

```
(umap vector [[0 1] [2 1]])        ; (4)
;=> ([0 2] [1 1])
```

So here's my question: am I reinventing the wheel?
Is there another way to do the same as (4)?

Bye and thanks in advance,

Alfredo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`apply` unpacks all of the elements in the sequence at the end of the argument list.

```
user> (apply map vector [[0 1] [2 1]])
([0 2] [1 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sure that I was reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 8):

It's not at all obvious that your `umap` works like a charm. In fact it will only work if you have the argument vector as a literal at compile time - which is exactly the times you could have passed multiple arguments to `map` anyway!

```
user> (umap vector [[1 2] [1 2]])
([1 1] [2 2])
user> (let [args [[1 2] [1 2]]]
        (umap vector args))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
[Thrown class java.lang.RuntimeException]
```

The macro only has access to the *symbol* `args` because it runs at compile time, and can't splice it in order to use map. The right answer is to use [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply), which treats its last argument as a sequence, and splices it into a series of additional arguments to the given function:

```
user> (let [args [[1 2] [1 2]]]
        (apply map vector args))
([1 1] [2 2])
```

Comment: Thanks amalloy, your answers are always useful!

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or does [mapcat](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/mapcat) work for your needs?

Comment: You must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. `mapcat` doesn't get him any closer to solving his problem.

Comment: Ahh, OK. I think I see what I was missing now.